# Importing excel file with read_excel function: Date columns is not correctly imported

Tags: r, tidyverse

I did the following code to import a excel file in Rstudio:

```
(nms <- names(read_excel("myexcelfile.xlsx")))
(ct <- ifelse(grepl("^Date", nms), "text", "numeric"))
read_excel("myexcelfile.xlsx", col_types = ct)[-c(6:495),-c(3:71)]
```

The resul is this dataframe below:

```
structure(list(Data = c("41731", "41730", "41729", "41726", "41725"
), ABEV3 = c(15.2, 14.9, 15.22, 15.15, 15.18)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The first column should be the dates (Brazilian Format: Day/Month/Year).

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(nms <- names(read_excel("myexcelfile.xlsx")))
(ct <- ifelse(grepl("^Date", nms), "date", "numeric"))
df <- read_excel("myexcelfile.xlsx", col_types = ct)[-c(6:495),-c(3:71)]

df$Date <- format(as.Date(as.character(df$Date)), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Instead of importing as text, import it as `date` and then format it in the way described below (there I suppose that you will save the Excel in the `df` dataframe and that the column will be called `Date`, but adjust as needed).

Comment: It doesnt work: I have this message: `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  string de caracteres não é um formato padrão não ambíguo`

Comment: I set arbitrarily: `as.Date(df$Date,origin = "1899-12-30")` and it works. Why?

Comment: This is the origin used by Excel. However I'm not sure why the approach above didn't work straight away, perhaps this is linked to different time zones.